# Linking Outlook Contacts to Dropdown List in VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Information in a VBA userform in Excel automatically transfers into an Excel sheet, which is then saved as a PDF and sent to email contacts defined in the source code.

Since the relevant mail recipients can vary, I want to include a dropdown list, where multiple recipients can be added.

Instead of adding dozens of contacts to that list, can I link the user's Outlook contacts to that dropdown list?

```vb
'PDF EXPORT
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlTypePDF, OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .To = "X@X.com"
    .Subject = "finished userform"
    .Body = "automatically sent mail. UserForm attached."
    .Attachments.Add varResult
    .Send        'automatically sends mail.
End With

UserForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Private Function GetOutlookAddressB() As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application, objAddressList As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim oItem As Outlook.AddressEntry, olNs As Outlook.NameSpace, i As Long, arrAddr
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAddressList = olNs.AddressLists("Contacts") '  if not returning contacts you can try
                                                       ' "Contacts (This computer only)", "Global Address List"
    ReDim arrAddr(objAddressList.AddressEntries.count - 1)
    For Each oItem In objAddressList.AddressEntries
        If oItem.Address <> "" Then
          arrAddr(i) = oItem.Name: i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    GetOutlookAddressB = arrAddr
End Function
```

In order to choose the appropriate address book for your case, please open Outlook, press the address book button (`Ctrl + Shift + B`) and see what address book name your installation uses. If not "Contacts", change it with the specific name'

The function can be called in order to create a validation list on "A1 cell of the active sheet (you can change the cell as you want):

```
Private Sub createListValidation()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, valCell As Range, arrAddress
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set valCell = sh.Range("A1") 'use here the cell you want
    arrAddress = GetOutlookAddressB
    With valCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arrAddress, ", ")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
  End With
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The above way of validation, using a custom list, works, but for a large number of addresses the custom list is accepted by Excel, you can see the validation working, but after saving and reopening the workbook it may have problems and "does not like it", anymore. For such a case, please use the next way. It drops the array content in a range (you can use a hidden sheet), and then uses the `Name` for list validation. This is not so compact/elegant, but it is safer:

```
Private Sub createListValidationNR() 'using a Named range
    Dim sh As Worksheet, valCell As Range, arrAddress
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set valCell = sh.Range("A1")         'use here the cell you want validating
    arrAddress = GetOutlookAddressB  'receive the address book in a 1D array
    'use here a sheet and a convenient cell, where to drop the array content and Name the range:
    valCell.Validation.Delete                'delete validation to not create a problem breaking the
                                                   'existing validation, if any...
    On Error Resume Next: sh.Parent.Names("myAddressBook").Delete 'delete the Name, if exists
    On Error GoTo 0
    With sh.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arrAddress) + 1, 1)
         .Value = Application.Transpose(arrAddress)  'drop the array content
         .Name = "myAddressBook"                       'create a named range
    End With
    With valCell.Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=sh.Parent.Names("myAddressBook")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarkAKE Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need?